# In TLS 1.3 handshake, what's "PSK binders" used for?

Tags: tls

PSK handhanke works like session ticket resumption in TLS 1.2, but I found a set of `PSK binder` for each identity(ticket) in TLS 1.3, why `PSK binder` are needed in TLS 1.3 ? To protect some attacks?

Comment: PreShareKey https://8gwifi.org/docs/tlsv13.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The current TLS 1.3 draft (-28) [talks about the binder value](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#appendix-E.1):

> The PSK binder value forms a binding between a PSK and the current
> handshake, as well as between the session where the PSK was
> established and the current session.  This binding transitively
> includes the original handshake transcript, because that transcript
> is digested into the values which produce the Resumption Master
> Secret.  This requires that both the KDF used to produce the
> resumption master secret and the MAC used to compute the binder be
> collision resistant.  See Appendix E.1.1 for more on this.  Note: The
> binder does not cover the binder values from other PSKs, though they
> are included in the Finished MAC.

So the idea seems to be that the binder value can be used to somewhat "prove" to the server that the client knows the pre-shared key associated with a given identity (and it's the same the server remembers). This also ensures that they won't just go ahead and run a PSK handshake when they don't actually have a PSK.

Additionally it binds the previous session ('s handshake) to the current session ('s handshake) which could e.g. allow the server to discover that the client previously suffered from a MitM attack when the attacker forwarded the identifier but naturally got a different PSK on both ends and is gone for the session resumption.

---

To see the first property have a look at [section 4.2.11.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-4.2.11.2) and [section 7.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-7.1). In section 7.1 you see that the `binder_key` is rather immediately derived from the `PSK`. Now for session resumption the `PSK` is the `resumption_master_secret`. But more importantly section 4.2.11.2 tells us

> The PskBinderEntry is computed in the same way as the Finished
> message (Section 4.4.4) but with the BaseKey being the binder_key
> derived via the key schedule from the corresponding PSK which is
> being offered

and so knowledge of the binder key immediately implies knowledge of the PSK. And knowledge of the binder key is confirmed by verifying the bound message.

Comment: I have dug through the TLS WG archives and [binders were introduced here](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg21482.html) but the concept was there before this.

Comment: Could you give me more information(example) about how the client can prove to server it knows psk and how the binders can protect the MitM.